# Python : Merge three lists of tuples according the first element of the tuple to add the seconds elements

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

I have three lists of tuples of size 2 given by :

```
a1 = [(47, 100)]
a2 = [(47, 100), (0, 86), (4, 86)]
a3 = [(47, 100), (39, 90)]
```

I want to merge them and remove the duplicates according the first element of the tuples. With the second, we add them. So we should get

```
a = [(47, 300) , (0, 86), (4, 86), (39, 90)]
```

How can i do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combined = a1 + a2 + a3
seen = set()
desired_output = [(a, b) for a, b in combined if not (a in seen or seen.add(a))]
```

**EDIT:**
I missed the part of the question of summing up the numbers. Sorry about that. Here is my edited answer addressing that part:

```
mydict = dict()

for a, b in combined:
   if a in mydict:
      mydict[a] += b
   else:
      mydict[a] = b

final_tuple = list(mydict.items())
```

Comment: By running your code I get `[(47, 100), (0, 86), (4, 86), (39, 90)]` . Th id 47 has a value 100 and not 300 as it should be

Comment: You are totally right. Sorry about that, I completely missed that part of the question. I have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
a1 = [(47, 100)]
a2 = [(47, 100), (0, 86), (4, 86)]
a3 = [(47, 100), (39, 90)]

out = {}
for l in [a1, a2, a3]:
    for x, y in l:
        out[x] = out.get(x, 0) + y

out = list(out.items())
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(47, 300), (0, 86), (4, 86), (39, 90)]
```